# Case insensitive string compare in Go template

Tags: templates, go, string-comparison, case-insensitive

Go template provides an `eq` comparison operator, e.g., `{{if eq .Var "val" }}`.

What's the best way to do a case insensitive string comparison in this case? So that the above would be true for Var to be "val", "Val", or "VAL".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`template.Funcs()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs) to register custom functions that you want to use in your templates.

There is a [`strings.EqualFold()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#EqualFold) function which performs case insensitive comparison of strings. So just register that function and you can call it from the template:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "MyEq": strings.EqualFold,
}).Parse(`"{{.}}" {{if MyEq . "val"}}matches{{else}}doesn't match{{end}} "val".`))

t.Execute(os.Stdout, "Val")
fmt.Println()
t.Execute(os.Stdout, "NotVal")
```

Result:

```
"Val" matches "val".
"NotVal" doesn't match "val".
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/EoyCh5KFEV).

Answer (score 4):

You can simply create another [lowercase](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ToLower) variable `s1 := strings.ToLower(s)` and to compare it with your template against a lowercase string.